# A way to work in Spring Integration (/Dsl) with DestinationResolvers

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Can I configure a single `JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` so it is able to work with different destinations, via `DestinationResolvers` or such? I'd like to provide the destination logic via the `IntegrationFlows` builder, so I can reuse the component (I don't need to create one adapter per topic), or centralize all destinations sources/decision rules in a single class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory())
                        .destination("DUMMY")
                        .configureListenerContainer(c ->
                                c.destinationResolver((session, s, b) ->
                                    YOUR LOGIC FOR DYNAMIC DESTINATION RESOLUTION)))
```

You need that `"DUMMY"` destination configuration to mock the container state:

```
protected void validateConfiguration() {
    if (this.destination == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Property 'destination' or 'destinationName' is required");
    }
}
```

OTOH I'm not sure that it is going to work properly anyway.

The container starts a JMS `Consumer` based on the destination (even if you provide it via the custom `DestinationResolver`) and it can't be changed until the container stop.

You can consider to use `Jms.inboundAdapter()` though, which is pollable, but based on the `JmsTemplate.receiveSelected()`. That way you can change a destination on each `receive()` invocation from the poller.

You will need `dummy` destinationName configuration there anyway. Otherwise it doesn't go to the `getDestinationResolver()`.

Comment: I realized by doing your code, that destinationResolver works in the other direction, so given a name it returns you the destination, what I need is being able to specify multiple topics for the adapter, so that from a given destination it returns me a name or something to tell apart subflows...

Comment: As you see by the `ListenerContainer` design it isn't possible. You can configure there only single destination.